# How do I get list of recent files in GNU Emacs?

Tags: emacs, ide

When I use Emacs I want to be able to easily display and navigate through a list of files I worked on from not just the current session but from previous sessions. (BTW, running Emacs 22.2 on Windows)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [Joe Grossberg](http://www.joegrossberg.com/archives/000182.html)'s blog (no longer available):

> But if you're using GNU Emacs 21.2
>   (the latest version, which includes
>   this as part of the standard distro),
>   you can just put the following lines
>   into your .emacs file
>
> ```
> ;; recentf stuff
> (require 'recentf)
> (recentf-mode 1)
> (setq recentf-max-menu-items 25)
> (global-set-key "\C-x\ \C-r" 'recentf-open-files)
> ```
>
> Then, when you launch emacs, hit
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>. It will show a list of
>   the recently-opened files in a buffer.
>   Move the cursor to a line and press
>   <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. That will open the file in
>   question, and move it to the top of
>   your recent-file list.
>
> (Note: Emacs records file names.
>   Therefore, if you move or rename a
>   file outside of Emacs, it won't
>   automatically update the list. You'll
>   have to open the renamed file with the
>   normal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> method.)
>
> Jayakrishnan Varnam has a [page
>   including screenshots](http://web.archive.org/web/20021114012120/http://varnam.org/e-recentf.html) of how this
>   package works.

*Note:* You don't need the `(require 'recentf)` line.

Comment: [screenshots no longer available](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2911420)

Answer (score 4):

Even if you don't have recentf turned on, Emacs is saving a list of files entered via the minibuffer in the variable `file-name-history`. Also, executing `(savehist-mode 1)` in your `.emacs` file makes that variable persist across invocations of Emacs.

So here's a little function that displays the files that actually exist from that list (anyone is welcome to use/build on this):

```
(defun dir-of-recent-files ()
  "See the list of recently entered files in a Dired buffer."
  (interactive)
  (dired (cons
      "*Recent Files*"
      (seq-filter
       'file-exists-p
       (delete-dups
        (mapcar (lambda (s) (string-trim-right s "/*"))
            file-name-history)
        ))))
  )
```

I find this quite useful and have it bound to one of those little special function keys on my desktop keyboard. (And so I have not seen the point of turning on recentf...)